# Use mask in opencv to detect color similarity

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, rgb

[image: red-img]

```
cv::Mat3b bgr = cv::imread("red_test.png");

cv::Mat3b hsv;
cvtColor(bgr, hsv, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);

cv::Mat1b mask1, mask2;
inRange(hsv, cv::Scalar(0, 70, 50), cv::Scalar(10, 255, 255), mask1);
inRange(hsv, cv::Scalar(170, 70, 50), cv::Scalar(180, 255, 255), mask2);

cv::Mat1b mask = mask1 + mask2;
```

In order to detect the red heart in the image, the code above when applied is applied which provides with 2 masked images namely 'mask1' and 'mask2'. Then I combine masks generated for both the red color range by doing an OR operation pixel-wise. The following output is generated.

[image]

**What I need to know is**: Is it possible to use the output image to detect red color in other sample images? (ignore the heart shape, it's only the color I'm interested in).

Comment: The mask just contains an equivalent of a boolean for each pixel, so you wont be able to detect the colour just from that.

Comment: is there another way that could be used?

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to do? Extract the colour of the masked part of your hsv image? Please edit your answer to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to make a comment, but it's not really possible to format it.

I can't run your code now, but by reading it I have some comments

1. The output is just a binary mask for the input image. It can be used for masking the red heart shape in the **input image**, but otherwise it's just a binary image with no relation to other images. I'd say it's won't do you any good for different shapes. In theory, you could use it to compute color model from the original image, but it won't get you anywhere since the model would just bring you back to your initial thresholding values (170:10 degree red, see point 2).
2. The two masks you are generating represent the color you are searching for and can be used for any image you want to find the red in range 170:10 degrees with further limits on the saturation and value. Those binary masks alone will tell you if there's any pixel in the range specified or not.
3. Now if you want to find if there's red or not in the image, you can just take the produced `mask` and sum the value of pixels, either with ````cv::sum`or`cv::countNonZero``` functions and see if the result is greater than 0.
4. For getting more parameters of the red object, you'd need to do some more, but the mask you produced is a good start, but your question was about just detecting, so not sure if you want any morphology down the line

Try running your code on any image with multiple colors and it will produce masks for whatever is red within the given range.